# AngularJS - Order a table's body matching the head

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table

```
<table>

    <thead>
        <tr class="">
            <th class="" ng-repeat="span in realm.spans">{{span.description}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="content-row" ng-repeat="row in realm.rows" ng-class="rowClass(row)" ng-click="markRow($event,row)">
            <td class="content-field" ng-repeat="(i,field) in row.fields track by $index>
                <input class="content-input" type="text" ng-model="row.fields[i]">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

How can i enforce the order used on `thead`, to be also used with the `td` elements in the table's body?

I have tried this:

```
 <td ng-repeat="(i,field) in row.fields track by $index | orderBy: realm.spans>
    <input type="text" ng-model="row.fields[i]">
 </td>
```

But that made no change

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this sample demo

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/45/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <table border="1">
     <th ng-repeat="header in headers"> <b>{{ headers[$index]}}</b></th>
     <tr ng-repeat="arr in records">
        <td ng-repeat="val in arr" ng-bind-html-unsafe="arr[headers[$index]]">
        </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('ArrayController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.headers = ['col1', 'col2'];
    $scope.records = [{
        col1: 'a1',
        col2: 'd1'
    }, {
        col1: 'c2',
        col2: 'A2'
    }, {
        col1: 'b3',
        col2: 'c3'
    }, {
        col1: 'd4',
        col2: 'a1'
    }, {
        col1: '11',
        col2: '22'
    }, {
        col1: 'E1',
        col2: 'E2'
    }];
});
```